# It there an equivalent to PHP's extract in Python?

Tags: php, python

Looking for the python equivalent of this.

http://php.net/extract

Comment: Please edit your answer with the additional information you provided in the comment to the answer below.

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose the answer that you chose. It is generally a bad idea to mess around with locals and unpacking the dictionary achieves what you need and is the more pythonic way. Any reason? I'm just wondering so I know what you really needed.

Comment: A "+1" to the Miles and Paolo. Extract and other PHP-like attempts at meta-programming are just simply scary. They're security faults waiting to happen, not to mention debugging nightmares. Some of the answers below have provided good advice on how to proceed, and while David Berger (who you accepted) has given the old college-try to meet the question head-on, from what I've seen of his answers on SO, I doubt he would actually use this approach in real-world, non-theoretical code.

Comment: (which isn't to say these approaches may not work in PHP... on that I cannot comment as I haven't used PHP in production in a couple years. When translated to Python, they are scary).

Comment: @Jarret: Just as scary in PHP. :)

Comment: PHP's extract() is itself scary.  It's the core of the register_globals functionality that is being purged with extreme prejudice in PHP 6, having been deprecated since PHP 4.1.

Comment: and when I say "deprecated since 4.1" I'm leaving out that it's been discouraged since PHP 3 came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One generally uses `locals()` to achieve this result, but the exact functionality is up to you.

```
>>> print apple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'apple' is not defined
>>> print banana
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'banana' is not defined

>>> variables = {"apple" : "a rigid, juicy fruit", "banana" : "a soft, fleshy fruit"}
>>> for variable,value in variables.iteritems():
...  locals()[variable] = value
... 
>>> print apple
a rigid, juicy fruit
>>> print banana
a soft, fleshy fruit
```

EDIT

Thanks to everyone who has diligently commented on the badness of this approach.  I wholeheartedly agree that **THIS IS  A BAD APPROACH**, and it deserves to be mentioned in the actual response for anyone who stumbles across this page.  (Never underestimate that; I saw this technique in a code snippet somewhere.  I can see why in that particular case it was harmless, but I know I can't go around encouraging bad methodology just because there are situations in which it won't break.)

Comment: The Python docs say about locals(): "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local variables used by the interpreter."  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html  

Furthermore, code that uses locals() is generally pretty unpythonic; there's almost always a better way to write things.

Comment: Not downvoting as this was an honest attempt to answer the question, but: don't ever do this.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you would be better off explaining what you are trying to do. Any solution to the direct question would be rather unpythonic as there is almost certainly a better way to do what you want.

**EDIT** (per your comments):

And indeed, there is a better way.

What you are trying to do is known as [`unpacking argument lists`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and can be done like this:

```
self.__api_call__('POST', '/api/foobar/', **mydict)
```

A working example:

```
>>> def a_plus_b(a,b):
...     return a+b
... 
>>> mydict = {'a':3,'b':4}
>>> a_plus_b(**mydict)
7
```

And it also works with kwargs, as you might expect:

```
>>> def a_plus_b(**kwargs):
...     return kwargs['a'] + kwargs['b']
... 
>>> a_plus_b(**mydict)
7
```

Answer (score 4):

no. why do you need it?

do the following (see comment)

```
def __api_call__(self, method, resource, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def do_call(my_dict):
    self.__api_call__('POST', '/api/foobar/', **your_dict)   # double asterisk!
```

Comment: def __api_call__(self, method, resource, **kwargs):
    # do stuff

def do_call(my_dict):
    self.__api_call__('POST', '/api/foobar/', <my_dict to args here>)

Is there a better way to do what I am thinking - don't want to change __api_call__'s use of kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is at least a nice theoretical question: how such construction can be implemented and how does it look like once it is applied?

For instance, as a function it can be implemented as

```
import inspect


def extract_attribute(obj, names):
    if type(names) == str:
        names = [names]
    # Get previous frame from the inspect stack.
    frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    try:        
        frame_locals = frame.f_locals        
        attributes = inspect.getmembers(
            obj, lambda attr: not inspect.ismethod(attr))        
        for name, attribute in attributes:
            if name.startswith('__') or name.endswith('__'):
                continue
            if name in names:
                frame_locals[name] = attribute
    finally:
        del frame
        del frame_locals
```

and used as

```
class A(object):
    foo = 'bar'


a = A()
extract_attribute(a, 'foo')
assert locals()['foo'] == 'bar'
assert foo == 'bar
```

Note: await pylint will complain on the last line. One can find *extract_attribute* function working with object in somewhat similar way to import functionality for modules. Applying it as additional layer of scope coupling (mixed with present import) will increase complexity of the code almost without exceptions.

*PS 
Obvious enough manipulating built-in is a sign of doing something python was not designed to do. But self-flattering mantras like not-practical and "non-pythonic" are not really proper arguments to me. In general it is always much more "practical" to make an experiment and to see if:
 1. Construction will enrich the expressiveness of the language (e.g. making it more readable and  natural-like), give new functionality, etc.
 2. Construction is too ugly and dangerous to be used, too flexible and unsafe, performance trade-offs are unacceptable, etc.
Illustration and test by explicit example is a preferred alternative. Looking at code everyone is free to make his own opinion without sharing the "professional guts" or copy-pasting religious dogmas. Please don't.*